Why did the cafeteria display flicker with the green, lush landscape rumored to be outside?
In Silo S01E03, when the generator is turned off and the silo switches to backup power, the cafeteria screen briefly flickers to a green and lush landscape before turning off, as if the mechanism generating the fake overlay lost power slightly before the real camera and screen itself. This indeed suggests that the image on the screen is faked.
(Spoiler for season finale below)

 In the final episode, it is revealed that the cafeteria screens indeed display the truth and that the suit helmets' displays are faked instead. In this case, what significance, if any, is there to the cafeteria display also briefly displaying the faked imagery?


Good question, I had the same one myself. Not having read the books, I assume it is explained later. As some commenters on other questions pointed out, this series has a very complex and deep (no pun intended) story, and so far, we have only seen the first half of the first of three books.
